# Spring Boot Response Body is different while running within Intellij vs Terminal

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, terminal

I have a simple spring boot application with a PostMapping. I respond with a text in the end that contains a table, basically this table is created by appending the lines after I run a command inside the spring boot app. Below is a ss with a bad formatting.
My problem is that this table is not correctly formatted when running the app inside the terminal by using (java -jar app.jar)[image]

Here is the good table while running from Intellij:[image]

This is the code that it's used to return this text.

```
@PostMapping("/newman")
public ResponseEntity<String> triggerNewmanTests(@Valid @RequestBody NewmanRequesBody requestBody) throws NewmanException {
    String uuidRequest = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    File directory = directoryService.createDirectory(requestBody.getLinkRepo(), uuidRequest);
    logger.info("Directory created under "+directory.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        gitService.cloneRepo(requestBody.getLinkRepo(), directory);
        logger.info("Directory cloned under "+directory.getAbsolutePath());
        StringBuilder newmanStringBuilder = newmanService.triggerNewman(
                requestBody.getLinkRepo(),
                requestBody.getEnvironment(),
                uuidRequest
        );
        logger.info(newmanStringBuilder.toString());
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newmanStringBuilder.toString(),responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

I have to mention that the log (logger.info(newmanStringBuilder.toString());) prints the text very good also in terminal, so basically something happens with the request, something may be added in the transportation in Intellij.

Comment: I believe this is due to logging level and nothing to do with IDE!

Comment: I just said that in the logs, everything looks fine, but when the request is finished and the response body contains the bad characters

Comment: From the screenshots, we see that they have basically the same output, but the Terminal ignores some escape sequences. It could also be that the application does not produce any escape sequences in intellij, and produces incorrect ones in terminal So the first thing I would do is to analyze whether the escape sequences are meaningful, and compare the seting of the `TERM` variable in both environments. Another interesting test would be to redirect the output to a file and have a look at this file with a hex editor.

Comment: I have the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue! Bassicaly the command that I have run, `newman run collection` returned a response with colors that were understood by the terminal[image]

Therefor Java added the color codes inside the response and it was actually printed out. Somehow Intellij removed these color codes from the response (I have no idea how, I can't find documentation on how Intellij actually runs the code)

The fix looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/newman")
public ResponseEntity<String> triggerNewmanTests(@Valid @RequestBody NewmanRequesBody requestBody) throws NewmanException {
    String uuidRequest = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    File directory = directoryService.createDirectory(requestBody.getLinkRepo(), uuidRequest);
    logger.info("Directory created under "+directory.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        gitService.cloneRepo(requestBody.getLinkRepo(), directory);
        logger.info("Directory cloned under "+directory.getAbsolutePath());
        StringBuilder newmanStringBuilder = newmanService.triggerNewman(
                requestBody.getLinkRepo(),
                requestBody.getEnvironment(),
                uuidRequest
        );
        logger.info(newmanStringBuilder.toString());
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        // This is the fix !
        final String msgWithoutColorCodes =
                newmanStringBuilder.toString().replaceAll("\u001B\\[[;\\d]*m", "");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(msgWithoutColorCodes,responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

After fixing this, the `java -jar app.jar` runs smooth, I get the good characters back in the response.

But in my context I'm running this jar inside a docker container which, again, broke my response. I've got:[image]

To fix this, you have to add locales inside your docker container, in my case adding this fixed the issue:

```
RUN apt-get -y install locales

# Set the locale
RUN sed -i '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //g' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```